# How to create a sequence of cell text with repeat and increment at intervals from another cell in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, sequence, array-formulas, repeat

I am trying to repeat a cells referance number I have set up in Column P.

I have typed what I want it to look like in olumn's Q and R.

But I would like to create a formula to have it update automatically based on the number from the cells in Column O.

So if the person bought 2 tickets i need the number to increment up by 1 and supply me with two ticket numbers for that persons order. While contuining on down the rows as they fill in.

Formual in Column P

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF($A$2:$A="","","PHLL24SR"&IF(ROW($A$2:$A)-1>=100,"0",IF(ROW($A$2:$A)-1>=10,"00","000")&(ROW($A$2:$A)-1))))
```

If i need to add more to the formual or change it or create the formula in column Q.

```
=REPT(P2&".",O2)
```

But could not get the increment number to be added behind the "."

Comment: Post few sample data then show your desired output.